# wait_for_any/when_any/WaitAny/WhenAny: What is the correct behavior when passed zero futures/tasks?

Tags: c++, boost, future

There are 4 design options to choose when `when_any` is passed zero futures, unfortunately all of them make sense.
Till now I am able to

1. summarize some weak arguments for each design option;
2. list some implementations and which design options they choose.

## Design option 1: `when_any(zero future<T>s)` should return a future that blocks forever.

The first reason is for the simplicity and uniformity of definition.

if when_any(zero futures) return a future that blocks forever, we get:

> wait_all blocks while some is unfinished, until all is finished;
> wait_any unblocks if some is finished, not if all is unfinished;

if when_any(zero futures) return a future that is immediately ready we get:

> wait_all blocks while some is unfinished, until all is finished;
> wait_any unblocks if some is finished, not if all is unfinished, but unblocks if there are zero futures;

The second reason is that `when_any` is an associative and commutative binary operation, so for variadic version of `when_any` we want to return the identity element of the `when_any` operation (which is a future that blocks forever). And in languages where you can define your own binary operators (may be C++ will do that in the future) or where the `std::accumulate` algorithm is supported, you will still encounter this identity element problem sooner or later.

> `when_all` is like `operator&&`, and in parameter pack expansion the empty pack expands to `true` for `operator&&`, `true` is like a future that is immediately ready.
> `when_any` is like `operator||`, and in parameter pack expansion the empty pack expands to `false` for `operator||`, `false` is like a future that is never ready.

(The other places where we need the identity element are:

- `boost::thread::null_mutex` to `std::scoped_lock` (`std::scoped_lock` is like an associative and commutative binary operation that consumes smaller locks and produce larger lock),
- `std::monostate` to `std::variant` (`std::variant` is like an associative and commutative binary operation that consumes smaller unions and produce larger union),
- empty set to `operator|` in regexp (an `operator|` node having zero children can happen if you write a program that convert NFA to regexp),
- empty string to `operator concat` in regexp,
- ...

)

**How should we treat divergence?**

a program might:

- produce a value;
- produce an error (the state of the program falls out of the domain of the evaluation function);
- diverge (for every state X, there exists a state Y that: X ---[evaluation function]--> Y);

**Divergence is not a value, divergence is not an error, divergence is divergence.**
There are programs that diverges (never terminates), such as operating system, protocol stack, database service and web server.
There are ways to deal with divergence. In C# we have cancelation functionality and progress report functionality. In C++ we can interrupt an execution agent (boost.thread) or destroy an execution agent (boost.context, boost.fiber). We can use thread safe queues or channels to send/receive values/errors to/from an actor continuously.

**use case for divergence①:**

A programmer uses library1 to consult some unreliable web service on an unreliable network. library1 retries forever because network is unreliable. library1 itself **shouldn't store an exception in the shared state when some timeout expires** because:

1. the application layer progrmmers may want to use different cancelation machanisms:

- when a timeout expires, or
- when the user clicks a button, or
- the user clicks a button to start a timeout and when the timeout expires;

2. the application layer programmers may want to do different things on cancelation:

- provide a default value, or
- provide an exception, or
- some programmers are not at the uppermost layer so they should not attach a cancelation machanism;

Anyway the programmer must use `when_any` to merge the potentially-block-forever future with his own my-cancelation/fallback-machanism future to get a larger future and the bigger future will not diverge now.
(Assume `when_any(several future<T>...)` returns `future<T>` so we don't have to write boilerplate code at every intermidiate when_any node in the future tree.)
(Some modifications required: (1) the bigger future that `when_any` returns should destroy other child futures when the first child future becomes ready; (2) library1 should use the promise object to check `if(shared_state.reference_count == 1)` and get to know that the consumer has abandoned the future (i.e. the operation is canceled), and quit that loop;)

**use case for divergence②:**

A programmer uses library2 to consult some unreliable web service on an unreliable network. library2 retries for n times and then blocks forever, not physically, but logically by setting a bit in the shared_state (`shared_state.diverge = true` or `stared_state.state = state_t::diverge`). The programmer use `when_any` to merge the future from library2 and the my-cancelation/fallback-machanism future. The first ready child future indicates the result. Suppose a failed child future becomes ready with an exception instead of blocking forever, then it answers the bigger future in place of the successful child future that becomes ready later, which is not desired.
(Assume `when_any(several future<T>...)` returns `future<T>` so we don't have to write boilerplate code at every intermidiate when_any node in the future tree.)

**use case for divergence③:**

When testing network code, use a future that is never ready to stand for a client that has very poor network condition, use a future that is immediately ready to stand for a client that has very good network condition, use futures with various timeouts to stand for clients that falls in between.
(Some modifications required: (1) add make_diverging_future; (2) add make_timeout_ready_future;)

## Design option 2: `when_any(zero future<T>s)` should return a future that contains an exception.

c++ - Non-polling implementation of std::when_any() - Code Review Stack Exchange
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176168/non-polling-implementation-of-stdwhen-any

> The Concurrency TS's [`when_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any) philosophically-incorrectly returns a ready future when called with zero arguments. My version doesn't treat that case specially, and so the natural behavior falls out: the internal `promise` is destroyed before any 1 of the 0 provided futures has become ready, and so `when_any(/*zero args*/)` returns a ready future whose `get()` will throw `broken_promise`.

I think this is a case of "Fail Early, Fail Loudly". Since he is treating divergence as an error, things become problematic in the above use cases.

## Design option 3: `when_any(zero future<T>s)` should return a future that contains a value of ???.

## Design option 4: `when_any(zero future<T>s)` should be forbidden.

The last 3 design options are used by the standards and libraries. I'll try to guess their motivation below.

Here are some implementations and their behaviours on *_all and *_any:
functions for CPU-bound programs:(**if you have trouble reading the table, go to edit mode**)

| where | function | behavior when passed zero tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| boost.thread *_all | `void wait_for_all(...)` | return `void` |
| boost.thread *_any | `iterator wait_for_any(...)` | return the end iterator |
| boost.fiber *_all | `void wait_all_simple(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `vector<R> wait_all_values(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `vector<R> wait_all_until_error(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `vector<R> wait_all_collect_errors(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `R wait_all_members(...)` | return a value of `R` |
| boost.fiber *_any | `void wait_first_simple(...)` | return `void` |
|  | `R wait_first_value(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `R wait_first_outcome(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `R wait_first_success(...)` | refused at compile time |
|  | `variant<R> wait_first_value_het(...)` | refused at compile time |
| System.Threading.Tasks *_all | `void Task.WaitAll(...)` | return `void` |
| System.Threading.Tasks *_any | `int Task.WaitAny(...)` | return `-1` |

functions for IO-bound programs:

| where | function | behavior when passed zero tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| std::experimental *_all | `future<sequence<future<T>>> when_all(...)` | return a future storing empty sequence |
| std::experimental *_any | `future<...> when_any(...)` | return a future storing `{ size index = -1, sequence<future<T>> sequence = empty sequence }` |
| boost.thread *_all | `future<sequence<future<T>>> when_all(...)` | return a future storing empty sequence |
| boost.thread *_any | `future<sequence<future<T>>> when_any(...)` | return a future storing empty sequence |
| System.Threading.Tasks *_all | `Task<TResult[]> Task.WhenAll(...)` | return a future storing empty sequence |
| System.Threading.Tasks *_any | `Task<Task<TResult>> Task.WhenAny(...)` | refused at run time (throw `ArgumentException`) |

(`System.Threading.Tasks.WaitAny(...)` accepts zero futures but `System.Threading.Tasks.WhenAny(...)` refuses at run time.)

The reason why we should not allow `when_any(zero tasks)` to return a future that blocks forever is perhaps practicality. If we allow that, we **open a hole in future's interface** saying that every future potentially diverges, so every application layer programmer has to use `when_any` to merge the future with my-cancelation/fallback-machanism future to get a bigger never-block future if he lacks further information, which is tedious. If we disallow that, we will protect those teams where not all interfaces are documented in detail (let me make an analogy: imagine you are in a C++ company where library functions receive and return potentially-`nullptr` pointers instead of `optional<reference_wrapper<T>>` and `reference_wrapper<T>`, without more information or documentation you have to guard every member access expression with `if(p)`, which is tedious; similarly with futures we have to do `when_any(future_returned_from_library, std::make_timeout_future(1s))` everywhere). So we'd better keep the interfaces and possibilities as small as possible.

(apologize to Alan Birtles: I'm sorry I made a mistake that day about the implementations listed: the wait_any functions of boost.fiber other than the first one forbids zero futures and there's a individual implementation that returns a future storing broken_promise (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176168/non-polling-implementation-of-stdwhen-any) so I am trying to summarize those in a new question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the standard solution: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any

> 0. If the range is empty (i.e., first == last), the returned future is ready immediately; the futures field of the when_any_result is an
>    empty vector, and the index field is size_t(-1).
> 1. If no argument is provided, the returned future is ready immediately; the futures field of the when_any_result is an empty
>    tuple, and the index field is size_t(-1).

Note also that most of the other "potentially desirable behaviours" can probably easily be composed just by adding an "empty" seed future to any received list:

```
 auto my_when_any = [](auto... f) {
     return when_any(EmptyT{}, f...);
 };
```

Here `EmptyT` could be a future that is always ready, is never ready, or holds an exception depending on your preference.

This is very similar to e.g. fold expressions where *you* decide the monoidal "seed": `(false || ... || pack)` vs. `(true && ... && pack)` as you referenced.